# Python split function behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

```
a = "1)2"
b = ")"
a = a.split(")")
b = b.split(")")
print(a, len(a), b, len(b))
```

returns

```
['1', '2'] 2 ['', ''] 2
```

This behaviour seems really strange to me. Why are blanks returned only for `b` and not `a`?

Comment: When you split b on the ")", there is nothing to the left or right of the ")", so you get empty strings.

Comment: For a, you have a 1 & 2 around the ```(```. For b, it's surrounded by nothing => Blank on each side.

Comment: What do you think the result should be instead, and why? What do you think `.split` does, and how do you think  it should handle the case where the delimiter appears at the beginning or end of the string? Also, did you try reading the documentation? What did it tell you about this?

Comment: You can see that another way: `your_separator.join([the split parts])` will always give you the original string. In `b`, your separator joins two empty strings, before and after itself. In `a`, it joins `"1"` and `"2"`

Comment: Questions asking "why" are not a good fit for Stack Overflow. We can try to give reasons why the decision that was made might make certain programming tasks easier or harder, but it's still very subjective. Ultimately, the reasoning is in the minds of the inventors - in this case, of the Python language. For this reason I am voting to close the question as opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was pointed out by others, the documented behavior of [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) explains your results. Since you specify `sep` to be `')'`, `split` looks for the strings that surround it, and in the case of `')'`, finds exactly 2 empty strings (**not** blanks). In the case of `'1)2'`, `split` finds 2 non-empty strings (`'1'` and `'2'`). Note that this behavior is extended to other similar cases, see below. As you can see, `split`, when provided with `sep`, returns empty strings in cases when the `sep` occur consecutively, or at the beginning or the end of a string.

```
lst = ['1', ')', '1)', ')2', '1)2', '1)2)', '))', ')1)2)']

for s in lst:
    s_split = s.split(')')
    print(f'"{s}" is split into\t{len(s_split)} element(s):\t', s_split)
```

Prints:

```
"1" is split into       1 element(s):    ['1']
")" is split into       2 element(s):    ['', '']
"1)" is split into      2 element(s):    ['1', '']
")2" is split into      2 element(s):    ['', '2']
"1)2" is split into     2 element(s):    ['1', '2']
"1)2)" is split into    3 element(s):    ['1', '2', '']
"))" is split into      3 element(s):    ['', '', '']
")1)2)" is split into   4 element(s):    ['', '1', '2', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because in the first case ( is encountered at index 1, so the result of split method will be [a[0:1],a[2:]]

Whereas in the first case ( is encountered at index 0
so split will return [a[0:0],a[0:]]

If you are still confused, consider a string s = "(12(3("

Here ( is encountered at 3 indices **0**,**3** and **5**
so split method returns [s[**0**:**0**],s[**0**+1:**3**],s[**3**+1:5],s[**5**+1:]]

Note:
The first and last elements will be something like s[**0**:i] and s[j:**-1**] respectively